# Codeigniter Class 'OAuth' not found in api in ci model

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

```
$key = $this->config->item('app_key_string');
    $secret= $this->config->item('app_secret');
    return $oauth = new OAuth($key, $secret);
```

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'OAuth' not found

Filename: /home/rosesand/etsy.rosesandbows.com/application/models/Etsy_api.php

Line Number: 32

Backtrace:

File: /home/rosesand/etsy.rosesandbows.com/application/controllers/App.php
Line: 35
Function: outh

File: /home/rosesand/etsy.rosesandbows.com/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Have you added OAuth library to your model ? how have you added  OAuth  library to CI?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added OAuth library to your model ? how have you added  OAuth  library to CI?

if every thing alright and you are using CI version more than 3 than you can rename the  OAuth class file by capitalize first letter .
i mean Like

**Oauth.php**

Comment: if you have placed it in application / library  folder and loaded to you controller or model from where it is used  with $this->load->library('oauth'); it should work or at least change the error massage

Comment: which OAuth library you have used ? if it is in git please provide the link if you like to have me a look .